# Changing directory using php passthru()

Tags: php

I want to change the working directory using passthru()  method and commandline ..

This is the php script

```
<?php
passthru("chdir C:/Documents and Settings/svn");
print passthru("dir");

?>
```

However, it is not changing the working directory to C:/Documents and Settings/svn..
It is outputting the files from the current directory ..
How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code has several issues:

1. [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) runs a new process, which may change *its own* current directory -- but this does not affect the current directory of the PHP process at all
2. `passthru` *prints* the output of the command, but it does not *return* anything; so the `print` at the end does nothing at all
3. it attempts to change the current directory even though it does not really need to

To fix the first two, use simply [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead of the first `passthru` and scrap the `print`:

```
chdir("C:/Documents and Settings/svn");
passthru("dir");
```

To fix all three:

```
passthru("dir \"C:/Documents and Settings/svn\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

When the command executed via passthru terminates, the current working directory is not propagated to PHP, because it is a child process, different from PHP.

In your case, you could append the wanted directory to the "dir" command, like this:

```
passthru("dir \"C:/Documents and Settings/svn\"");
```

I don't recommend directly using the PHP `chdir()` function in your case, because it could have nasty side-effects, especially if you're including other PHP files from your script.
It also might not work as expected if you are using safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

passthru("chdir C:/Documents and Settings/svn; dir");